# HttpResponseMessage post API json format with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I used the HttpResponseMessage Post method to let the mobile terminal verify the account password. I used the following CODE to run successfully, but the POST format must be run like this.

```
'{"ID":"xxx","Password":"xxx"}'
```

It need two ' can run, I don't know why.
I can't request a service using the normal POST format on iOS or Android.
The format I want is `{"ID":"xxx","Password":"xxx"}`,without '

```
  [HttpPost]

        public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] string DATA)
        {
            using (appapidataEntities entities = new appapidataEntities())
            {
                //string controllerName = ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
                JObject jo = JObject.Parse(DATA);
                string id = jo["ID"].ToString();
                string password = jo["Password"].ToString();
                var user = entities.USERs.Where(x => x.ID == id && x.Password == password).FirstOrDefault();
                var result = new
                {
                    message = "failure"
                };
                var result2 = new
                {
                    message = "success"
                };

                if (user == null)
                {
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
                }
                else
                {
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result2);
                }
            }
        }
```

```
public partial class USER
   {
       public string ID { get; set; }
       public string Password { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Please have someone with experience to help me, thank you very much.

Comment: Why not using model binding? Also what platform is this code running on?

Comment: running ASP.NET "using model binding" what is that mean?

Comment: what version of ASP.NET? Asp.net Web API 2, Asp.net Core,...etc?

Comment: refresh page and check my previous comment

Comment: "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net452"  API 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Nkosi said, the correct way to receive a complex object is using a class/object (also called 'model binding')

In your models add this class. This class will be the 'contract' between the service with any external application who calls the service. Usually, any client (service, app or frontend) also has a class with this contract to call the service.

```
public class LoginViewModel {
   public string ID  { get; set; }
   public string Password  { get; set; }
}
```

Now, modify the controller as follow

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] LoginViewModel DATA) {
   using (appapidataEntities entities = new appapidataEntities())           
        string id = DATA.ID;
        string password = DATA.Password;

       // rest of the code
   }
}
```

Make sure the device is sending the data the service is waiting  (maybe adding a breakpoint if you are debugging from Android Studio before to make the request) and add a breakpoint in your controller to verify that the variable DATA has the correct values.